# Ubuntu 16.04.2 Problem With USB Wifi adapter, Kernel suddenly hangs

Tags: networking, wireless

I have tried to reinstall ubuntu using Ubuntu 16.04.2 ISO. Got no problem with fresh install from ISO and able to connect via Wifi adapter.

But after update to latest, the issue come up again with kernel suddenly hangs, no respond whatsoever.

Seems DHCP resolver trough USB Wifi Adapter is the problem but i don't know how to debug it or solve it.

lsusb output (Important device):

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

lsmod | grep rtl

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
rtl8192cu              65536  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              761856  5 iwlmvm,rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             557056  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
cfg80211              581632  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,rtlwifi
```

I use USB wifi to extend my signal recive. My room is blocking the wifi signal. Its work fine at Windows 10, older Ubuntu 16.04.1, and fresh ISO 16.04.2. But kernel hangs after update to latest patch.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: lsusb

Comment: What is wrong with the internal wifi?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsmod | grep rtl`